# Indented paragraph next to a box

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, indentation, boxes

I am trying to indent a whole paragraph to the right of a numbered box. However, the paragraph does not appear vertically aligned with the box. I am using the below code:

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \boxed{}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath

\begin{document}
\boxed{\textbf{R1.1}} 

\setlength{\leftskip}{1.45cm}
\noindent \textit{The central goal of the SHRP 2 Safety research program was 
to address the role of driver performance and behavior in traffic safety. 
This included developing an understanding of how the driver interacts with 
and adapts to the vehicle, traffic environment, roadway characteristics, 
traffic control devices, and the environment. It also included assessing the 
changes in collision risk associated with each of these factors and 
interactions. This information will support the development of new and 
improved countermeasures with greater effectiveness.}

\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you include your preamble as well?

Comment: It is included now.

Comment: What do you mean by "aligned"? Do you want the text to start right under the frame of the box?

Comment: @Bubaya No, I want the whole paragraph to be indented to the right of the box such that the first paragraph line starts on the same line of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the paragraph is supposed to be put next to the box, an immediate solution would be to use command `\llap`, which suppresses the width of the box:

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \boxed{}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath

\begin{document}
\setlength{\leftskip}{1.45cm}

\noindent%
\llap{%
    \boxed{\normalfont\textbf{R1.1}}%
    \hspace{1em}%
}%
\textit{%
    The central goal of the SHRP 2 Safety research program was 
    to address the role of driver performance and behavior in traffic safety. 
    This included developing an understanding of how the driver interacts with 
    and adapts to the vehicle, traffic environment, roadway characteristics, 
    traffic control devices, and the environment. It also included assessing the 
    changes in collision risk associated with each of these factors and 
    interactions. This information will support the development of new and 
    improved countermeasures with greater effectiveness.
}

\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}
\end{document}
```

However, a better solution would be using lists. For this, [`enumitem`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) is a very handy package for manipulating lengths involved in `itemize`, `enumerate` or `description` environments:

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \boxed{}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=1.45cm, labelwidth=1.2cm, labelsep=2.5mm]
\item[\boxed{\normalfont\textbf{R1.1}}]
    The central goal of the SHRP 2 Safety research program was 
    to address the role of driver performance and behavior in traffic safety. 
    This included developing an understanding of how the driver interacts with 
    and adapts to the vehicle, traffic environment, roadway characteristics, 
    traffic control devices, and the environment. It also included assessing the 
    changes in collision risk associated with each of these factors and 
    interactions. This information will support the development of new and 
    improved countermeasures with greater effectiveness.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]